# Change data.frame in *_ply function

Tags: r, plyr

Let's say I have

```
a <- data.frame( z = rep( c("A", "B", "C"), 2 ), p = 1:6, stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
b <- data.frame( z = c( rep( "A", 5), rep( "B", 5 ) ), q = 1:10, stringsAsFactors=FALSE  )
```

and want to manipulate `a` while iterating over `b` using `plyr` functions, for example

```
library(plyr)
d_ply( b, "z", function( x ){
  a[ a$z == x[1, "z"], "p" ] <<- a[ a$z == x[1, "z"], "p" ] + sum(x$q)
})
```

In this case I have to use `<<-` for the assignment in order to change `a` outside the `d_ply`. If I use only `<-` `a` won't change. What I definitely want to avoid is iterating over `a` since `b$z` contains only a very small subset of `a$z`.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a simple and performant solution using `plyr` which avoids the `<<-`?
2. Is there another handy solution (maybe except `for( i in unique(b$z) ){ ... }`)?
3. If I stick with my solution, are there any implications using the `<<-` in this way? Can I be sure that under any circumstance only the closest `a` (in terms of environments) to the `d_ply` call will be manipulated? Especially since this is all part of a ReferenceClass method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an option using `data.table` instead of `plyr`

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(a, key="z")
b <- data.table(b, key="z")

a[b[, sum(q),  by=z], p := p + V1]

   z  p
1: A 16
2: A 19
3: B 42
4: B 45
5: C  3
6: C  6
```

#### Edit:

Regarding your third question and using `<<-`, I would advise against it. 
If you want to assign into a different environment, use the `assign(., envir=.)` function which allows you to specify which environment to assign into.

Comment: I like this solution, but will wait with accepting it. My main concern is about the third question I had.